# Utilizar PlaceAutocompleteFragment dentro de un Fragment Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

Estoy tratando de utilizar PlaceAutocompleteFragment dentro de mi fragment donde tambien tengo un SupportMapFragment, al principio cuando la aplicacion inicia todo funciona perfectamente, pero si me muevo a otro fragment y despues con el menu regreso de nuevo al fragment del mapa este truena.

En my xml tengo:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />


   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
       android:id="@+id/content_fragment_places"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible">

      <fragment
         android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

En mi Fragment Tengo:

```
    public class MapLocalizacionFragment extends Fragment implements      OnMapReadyCallback, 
    OnCameraIdleListener,
GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener,
        GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveCanceledListener,
GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, 
PlaceSelectionListener {

    private static View VIEW;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    GoogleMap map;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    VIEW = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    mapFragment= (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

        autocompleteFragmentPartida.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);
}

   @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
    //ubico mapa con cordenadas
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

        }


}
```

El Error que obtengo es :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                 at com.taxi.user.cnc.fragmentsmenu.MapLocalizacionFragment.onCreateView(MapLocalizacionFragment.java:370)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #73: Duplicate id 0x7f0f0143, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0f0142 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4669)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:36)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                 at com.taxi.user.cnc.fragmentsmenu.MapLocalizacionFragment.onCreateView(MapLocalizacionFragment.java:370) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

probe usando un try catch en `VIEW = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);` El resultado fue que se mostraba el fragment con el PlaceAutocompleteFragment funcionando perfectamente pero el mapa no se muestra bien, tiene funcionalidad se ven los controles y entra a los listeners, pero el mapa se queda en un color solido. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cual Podria ser el problema o Como lo puedo solucionar?.

**EDIT**

Mi mapa funciona no es problema del api key ya que cuando arranco la aplicaion se muestra perfectamente.
Uso esta linea cuando inicia la app:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MapLocalizacionFragment()).commit();
```

Aqui todo bien pero cuando doy clic en el menu para regresar a este mismo fragment pasa lo ya mensionado. en mi menu utilizo la misma linea para iniciar el fragment.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MapLocalizacionFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: En la esquina dice "Google", eso quiere decir que si corresponde al maps. ¿creo que no agregaste la api de maps? https://console.cloud.google.com
esto se define en el manifest

Comment: @Maguz 
Eso ya lo tengo en mi manifest: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="mi api key" />. Al arrancar la aplicacion funciona el mapa perfectamente pero cuando doy clic en el menu llamo a getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.‌​container, new MapLocalizacionFragment()).commit();  es aqui donde pasa el error.

Comment: El error te dice que hay duplicado de ids, mírate la sección de carga de los fragmentss donde puedes controlar si un fragment està en la pila, rescatarlo